# How to catch creation of DOM elements and manipulate them with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I'm trying to devise a method of when adding a simple div element with a class and some data-* in it, it will replace it or add into it some other elements. This method should not be called manually, but automatically by some kind of .live() jQuery method, a custom event or some kind like $('body').bind('create.custom'), etc.
I need it this way since I wouldn't know in advance what elements will be created since they will be served through ajax like single empty div's or p's .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title >on create</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" >

            jQuery(function($){
                $("div.fancyInput").each(function(index,element){

                    var $div = $(this);
                    var dataId = $div.attr("data-input-id");
                    var inputId = '';
                    var labelId = '';
                    if(!!dataId){
                        inputId = 'id="' + dataId + '"';
                        labelId = 'id="' + dataId + 'Label"';
                    } // if

                    var dataValue = $div.attr();

                    $(
                        '<p class="fancyInput" >' +
                        '    <label ' + labelId + ' for="' + inputId + '" >A fancy input</label>' +
                        '    <input ' + inputId + ' name="' + inputId + '" value="A fancy input" />' +
                        '</p>'
                    ).appendTo($div);               
                }); // .each()
            }); // jQuery()
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" >

            jQuery(function($){
                var counter = 2;
                var $form = $('#form');
                $('#add').click(function(event){
                    $('<div class="fancyInput" data-input-id="fancyInput' + counter + '" ></div>').appendTo($form);
                    counter++;
                }); // .click
            }); // jQuery()

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a id="add" href="#" > add another one </a>
        <form id="form" action="#" >

            <p class="normalInput" >
                <label id="normalInputLabel" for="normalInput" >A normal input</label>
                <input id="normalInput" name="normalInput" value="A normal input" />
            </p>

            <div class="fancyInput" ></div>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update:**
I checked liveQuery beforehand, it's that kind of functionality that I need, but with the ability to modify DOM elements while the event callback is executed. So it's not just that I need events attached, but the ability to modify the DOM upon element creation. For example: whenever a new  is created, it should be filled in (even better if replaced) with the p, label and input tags

Answer (score 4):

You could use a DOM Level 3 Event, like `DOMNodeInserted`. This could look like:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    // A new node was inserted into the DOM
    // event.target is a reference to the newly inserted node
});
```

As an alternative, you might checkout the [`.liveQuery`<sup>help</sup>](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) jQuery plugin.

**update**

In referrence to your comment, have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html, only browser which do not support it are the Internet Explorers of this this world (I guess IE9 does at least).

I can't say much about the performance, but it should perform fairly well.

Comment: I read somewhere that it's slow, and may not be supported on all browsers.

Comment: Question: Would it be faster/better if you bound directly to the inserted element using `.live()` instead?

Comment: @Victor: it depends on what you want to achieve. If you only want to have event handlers on certain events, sure you **should** use `.live` or `.delegate`, but if you want to call certain methods on newly inserted nodes for instance, you need do it the way I suggested.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but livequery will not cut it, and its not just a simple events attachment problem, please check the update