# Have newly added DOM elements use function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following set in my JS:

```
$('.selector').selectpicker();
```

When new DOM elements are added to the page, the above method doesn't work on the new DOM elements. I know that, in other cases, I can do the following such that newly added DOM elements work:

```
$(document).on("click", ".class-here", function() {

});
```

But how can a method like the first changed to work with new DOM elements (rather than calling that same method again)?

Comment: you need to call it after the new elements added

Comment: Is that a bootstrap function?

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: @MauricePerry what Ehsan Sajjad is suggesting is that immediately after you add the `.selector` element in jQuery, you should call that function. It's difficult to tell what you have done, though, without more code.

Comment: @Jason I was talking about .selectpicker(). I don't know this method.

Comment: @MauricePerry `.selectpicker()` enables an element as a "selectpicker." You must call that method whenever you add a new selectpicker. It should be noted that selectpickers and the .selectpicker() method are *not* included by default in Bootstrap. You must download selectpicker from http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the level 3 event for DOM node creation, like  `.on("DOMNodeInserted",(selector),(function))` to execute your function whenever an element fitting the selector is inserted. See [How to catch creation of DOM elements and manipulate them with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915387/how-to-catch-creation-of-dom-elements-and-manipulate-them-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on the function you're calling (here selectpicker).

If you're talking about the bootstrap function, you would do:

```
$('.selector').selectpicker("refresh");
```

After having changed the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is regarding binding new element in DOM, Prior version of jquery use bind and unbind method for new element in dom.

But If you use jQuery 1.3+ then you can write

```
     $('selector').live('event',function (){ //do some action });
```

In above jquery, You didn't need to bind/unbind element on DOM.

But latest version of jQuery 1.7+, You can directly use .on() method which you mentioned above, It mean that you didn't care to bind, unbind on 'DOM change'.

On() is simple that you can write common callback for multiple events on particular selector.

I hope that this details is useful to you and you got your answer. If you use 'on()' then you not need to bind element in DOM.

Comment: You should replace `$(selector)` with `$('.selector')`.

Comment: Thanks, 'selector' can be anything like class, id, dom element, So write it in single quotes! Thanks for comment.

Comment: OP is already using a version of jQuery that supports `.on()` so to start your answer with `.live()` is somewhat ignorant of that fact.